# Ransack filter by multiple values or nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have an API written using jsonapi.rb and Ransack.

My model has a **Car** with **color** attribute, which is an integer or nil.
I would like to be able to filter this attribute by multiple color numbers or empty values. It would look like this:

```
/cars?filter[color_in]=1,2,nil
```

Ransack can search by multiple values, or it can filter by null values.
But how can I pass an empty value to Ransack here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way out is to convert a null to another value and search by it.
In my case column is an integer, so I want to convert null to 0 for all attributes I want to filter by.

Add to model:

```
ransacker :color do
  Arel.sql('COALESCE(color, 0)')
end
```

Then search with:

```
/cars?filter[color_in]=1,2,0
```

So query will look like:

```
WHERE COALESCE(color, 0) IN ('1', '2', '0')
```